# Android one symphony roar a50 update to lollipop 5.1 error

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, updates

After I updated my **Symphony roar a50** phone I got an error which says

> Signature not valid.

As I experienced some of these model get updated properly. 
Has anyone encountered this problem so far? How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: this site is not for what you are looking!!

Answer (score 1):

Download the ZIP file of OTA UPDATE from below link:

http://ota.googlezip.net/packages/ota/google_roara50sprout_roara50/e2904c9fc284d15fb4f52e818c328897d1d5f89d.signed-sprout-roar-a50-ota-1783956.e2904c9f.zip

Then place the zip file in memory card. Turn off your phone. (Make sure you have more than 80% charge in battery). Boot into stock recovery or any other recovery (Hold the volume up button and power button together to power up). Select "apply update from sd card". Select the downloaded zip file. Your android device will process the upgrade automatically and will be rebooted. That's all. Enjoy your lollipop. :)